# Get Phone Number of real device

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-native

I need some help. I need take phoneNumber of device . Iam using cordova-plugin-sim. Heres my code

```
this.sim.getSimInfo().then(
(info) => browser.on(“loadstop”)
.subscribe(
() => {
console.log(info.phoneNumber);
alert(info.phoneNumber+’ '+info.cards[0].phoneNumber);
},
err => {
console.log("InAppBrowser loadstart Event Error: " + err);
}),
(err) => console.log('Unable to get sim info: ', err)
);
```

But i had a problem. In my emulator everything work great, but on my real device i had undefind when i try outpu phoneNumber? other parameters work great. Where is problem? I ask all permissions on the start of app

```
this.sim.hasReadPermission().then(
(info) => console.log('Has permission: ', info)
);

    this.sim.requestReadPermission().then(
        () => console.log('Permission granted'),
        () => console.log('Permission denied')
    );
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fetch current sim number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15225835/how-to-fetch-current-sim-number)

Comment: Phone number is not always stored in SIM Card. Only solution, generate a call or a send a SMS to your backend

Comment: @LaurentY thank you for your answer.